# Uploads folder only showing files up to the letter "P"

Tags: media-library, uploads

I have recently migrated a website and for the uploads folder I just downloaded the whole thing via FTP. In the new website I am missing a few images. I noticed it's only the images that start after the letter P and if I look both my origin website and my new one and order the files alphabetically, it stops at the letter P. I am missing all of the files that start with R, S, etc...Is there any explanation for this? Can a upload folder be full or something?

Comment: Space restrictions would more likely be a hosting restriction than WordPress. Have you checked the FTP client's logs to see if there were errors or if the connection closed before all files could be downloaded?

Comment: It was a limit set by the host you are right.